# Update Multi-field Completion Suggester Weighting

Tags: elasticsearch

Given the following mapping:

```json
{
  "index-name-a" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "fields" : {
            "suggest" : {
              "type" : "completion",
              "analyzer" : "standard",
              "preserve_separators" : true,
              "preserve_position_increments" : true,
              "max_input_length" : 50
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I update the weightings of individual documents? I have tried the following:

```json
PUT /index-name-a/_doc/1
{
  "title.suggest" : {
    "weight" : 30
  }
}
```

Which errors with:

> Could not dynamically add mapping for field [title.suggest]. Existing mapping for [title] must be of type object but found [keyword]

Which makes sense, since the property is of type keyword and not an object. But I can't find the correct way to do it. Closest I could find [in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/search-suggesters.html#indexing) doesn't seem to work if it's a multi-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

Indeed I could reproduce this behaviour on elasticsearch v `8.1`

```json
PUT /72342475-2/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "preserve_separators": true,
        "preserve_position_increments": true,
        "max_input_length": 50,
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT 72342475-2/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "title": ["nevermind", "smell like teen spirit"],
  "title.weight": 22
}
```

Comment: Annoying that the index had to be dropped and recreated but this workaround does produce the correct results.